What should be my classifier in Transfer Learning using MaxViT?
I am trying to do transfer learning on Pytorch pretrained models with custom dataset. I have been able to successfully perform transfer learning with SqueezeNet.
For Squeezenet my classifier was, layers source
model.classifier = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Dropout(p=0.2),
    nn.Conv2d(512, len(class_names), kernel_size=1),
    nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
    nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((1, 1)))

For Efficientnet my classifier was, layers source
model.classifier = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Dropout(p=0.2, inplace=True),
    torch.nn.Linear(in_features=1280,
                    out_features=output_shape,
                    bias=True))

Similarly I have been trying to do for MaxViT, I went through the source and saw that there are block_channels[-1] in parameter. I have recently started with this, and I don't know what they are, layers source
self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
    nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(1),
    nn.Flatten(),
    nn.LayerNorm(block_channels[-1]),
    nn.Linear(block_channels[-1], block_channels[-1]),
    nn.Tanh(),
    nn.Linear(block_channels[-1], num_classes, bias=False),
)

For reference, if needed, following is my complete code for performing transfer learning using squeezenet.
weights = torchvision.models.SqueezeNet1_0_Weights.DEFAULT
model = torchvision.models.squeezenet1_0(weights=weights).to(device)
auto_transforms = weights.transforms()
train_dataloader, test_dataloader, class_names = data_setup.create_dataloaders(train_dir=d1,
                                                                               test_dir=d2,
                                                                               transform=auto_transforms,
                                                                               batch_size=32)
for param in model.features.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False

torch.manual_seed(42)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(42)
output_shape = len(class_names)

model.classifier = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Dropout(p=0.2),
    nn.Conv2d(512, len(class_names), kernel_size=1),
    nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
    nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((1, 1))).to(device)

loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
torch.manual_seed(42)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(42)
results = engine.train(model=model,
                       train_dataloader=train_dataloader,
                       test_dataloader=test_dataloader,
                       optimizer=optimizer,
                       loss_fn=loss_fn,
                       epochs=15,
                       device=device)

What should my classifier be for MaxViT?

From MaxVit Args parameters:

block_channels (List[int]): Number of channels in each block. Source

The classifier Source
self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
        nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(1),
        nn.Flatten(),
        nn.LayerNorm(block_channels[-1]),
        nn.Linear(block_channels[-1], block_channels[-1]),
        nn.Tanh(),
        nn.Linear(block_channels[-1], num_classes, bias=False),
    )

Since block_channels is a list,`block_channels[-1] returns the last item in the list, 512 in the following case Source
return _maxvit(
    stem_channels=64,
    block_channels=[64, 128, 256, 512],
    block_layers=[2, 2, 5, 2],
    head_dim=32,
    stochastic_depth_prob=0.2,
    partition_size=7,
    weights=weights,
    progress=progress,
    **kwargs,
)


Thanks for your reply, but how am I supposed to return the channel, could you please help me with this code
model.classifier = nn.Sequential(nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(1), nn.Flatten(),  nn.LayerNorm(channel),  nn.Linear(channel, channel),  nn.Tanh(), nn.Linear(channel, len(class_names), bias=False) )
What should be the channel variable?
